# indent-region has strange behavior. Why my indent-region style for my c++-mode doesn't work properly?

Tags: emacs, indentation

I had this old fashion init.el config:

```
(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4)
```

but over time it become like that for some reason:

```
namespace MyGui {
    
    class FastCombo
    {
    public:
        FastCombo(const std::string& label, std::vector<std::string>& values, size_t& preview_index)
            {
                preview_index++;
                if (ImGui::BeginCombo(label.c_str(), values[preview_index].c_str()))
                {
                    
                }
                
            }
        ~FastCombo()
            {
                ImGui::EndCombo();
            }
    };
    
}
```

I tried to change my config to this:

```
(setq c-default-style '(("c++" . "linux")
                        (java-mode . "java")
                        (awk-mode . "awk")
                        (other . "gnu")))
```

but it gives me:

```
FastCombo(const std::string& label, std::vector<std::string>& values, size_t& preview_index)
{
    preview_index++;
    if (ImGui::BeginCombo(label.c_str(), values[preview_index].c_str()))
        {
                    
        }
        
}
```

I checked my modes I had minor c++-mode turned on.

Comment: what indentation do want?  That looks like the `linux` style.  Your `c-default-style` should be mapping `major-mode` to style, eg. `((c++-mode . "linux") ...)` not `(("c++" . ...))`.  So, youre seeing `gnu` style in the last snippet since there is no entry matching `c++-mode` - youre getting the indentation associated with fallback `other`. Use `M-x c-set-style` to find the one you want